# Is this a great flaw in big bang theory?

Tags: spacetime, time, universe, space, big-bang

Einstein said that, Time & Space cannot exists without one another. Big bang says, time didn't exist before the big bang. So the Primordial ball referred in the Big Bang theory didn't had any space inside it ??

If primordial ball had space in it, then where did the time go ??

Is this a flaw in big bang theory ??

Or Am I missing something ??

Comment: Maybe the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang) will help you get a clearer picture, so you can get back here and ask a more physically relevant question. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5150/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you have entirely the wrong idea of what the Big Bang is. have a look at [How is it possible to come to a conclusion that Universe is a result of the Big Bang while we aren't able to observe the entire Universe?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/41717/how-is-it-possible-to-come-to-a-conclusion-that-universe-is-a-result-of-the-big/41762), then search this site for "FLRW metric" for more background.

I very nearly suggested closing your question as a duplicate of the question I linked above because the subject matter is very similar. However the two questions are not really duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

The primordial ball could not have had space in it unless the ball itself was "in space". That is part of the universe which cannot be seen, and thus cannot be theorized about. Wherever and whenever the primordial ball was is beyond the scope of physics I think.