# Is the big bang a fact?

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion, big-bang

I have watched many physics debated and in everyone of them, physicists take big bang for granted. But, is the big bang actually proven, or there are many evidence that indicate that it did happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What has been proved about the big bang, and what has not?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11136/)

Comment: What i essentially ask is if we can accept big bang as a fact or not, because physicist seem to do so...

Comment: "is the big bang actually proven?". Science is different from mathematics: nothing in science is ever "proven". All we can do is to see how well it stacks up against observations - which the big bang does very well, so far.

Answer (score 3):

There are [scientists that do not accept the Big Bang](http://homepages.xnet.co.nz/~hardy/cosmologystatement.html) (and [more](http://www.cosmology.info/)). That doesn't mean that there isn't evidence for the Big Bang (there is), nor does it imply it may be wrong.

All we can say is that some scientists consider the Big Bang to be a fact because the evidence is overwhelming, some who think it is the best cosmological model because there is much evidence *consistent* with it, and then there are those who do not accept the Big Bang because they believe there is significant evidence against it.

Answer (score 2):

@GeorgeSmyridis: the big bang is a model that describes a bunch of cosmology.  Physicists, when referring to it, rarely are talking about the event that happened at the very beginning of the model.  In fact, the situation in the model goes outside of the applicable region of known physics before you get to the point in time when the explosion would have happened.  All we can say is that, as you go back in time, you reach a very hot, very dense state some 13.7 billion years ago.