# Is the universe actually formed according to the big bang theory?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, universe, big-bang, white-holes

Big-Bang pretty much explain the origin of universe, but still many people don't believe it. Isn't it possible that our universe come out of a white hole which have been pulled out from a black hole that was in some other universe?

Comment: By "formation" do you mean "origin" or "the development of the structure that we see today"?   Those are two different things, and will elicit different answers.

Comment: I mean the origin (how it was created).

Comment: why you didnt consider that black hole was pulled out of another black hole which was pulled out of a white hole?

Comment: @(LOL*11)  Lol that was so much beyond my level. Had a hard time figuring it out ;)

Comment: Related: [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/)

Comment: False and false.

Comment: Can't understand what is unclear in this.

Comment: To reopen this post (v3) consider to only ask only [one question](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6833/2451).

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11136/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

No one knows.

One other thing ... the big bang hypothesis does not explain the origin of the universe (although I recognize that you used the word "formation", not "origin", but I'm not sure what exactly you meant by "formation").  It explains what happens after a certain epoch in our universe's history.  What happens before that is completely unknown.  What we call the big bang might occur a tiny fraction of a second before the creation of the universe, or many billions of years after the creation of the universe.   All that assuming that the universe had a creation event.