# Is there any credible evidence for big bang?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, space-expansion, big-bang

The big bang model is first discussed when the people witnesses that almost every galaxies are speeding away from each other suggesting that at one point in time or more accurately at $t=0$ everything including space-time have to be congregated together. Is there any truth to this model?

Comment: Give [Ned Wright's Cosmology Tutorial](http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~wright/cosmo_01.htm) a read.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11136/2451

Comment: No, it's all made up: almost everyone working in cosmology and all the refereed journals are part of a giant conspiracy (the aim of which is unclear), while a tiny number of people publishing on the internet are the only ones to see the truth.  Almost all 'big science' is like this: you should never trust the mainstream but always seek out the fringe.  Personally, I find the best single criteria is whether the author uses many colours for their text: those pages are always the best.  It used to be crayons, of  course.

Comment: @tfb, It is just that sarcasm, arrogance, *hubris* has made public opinion hate and despise, alas, *all science* , scientists and physics: just because ofsuch sloppy, lame theories. Come down to earth and get another attitude and concede the limits of such *scientific* theories

Comment: A really poor question. There is of course lots and lots of evidence and plenty of freely available accounts of that evidence. If you have a problem understanding some element of how that evidence was gathered or how it supports (not proves) the big bang model or falsifies other ideas, then come back witha specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Big Bang is the prevailing cosmological model because there is plenty of evidence supporting it. There’s some confusion on this page regarding what scientific evidence is. A model is evidenced by the empirical success of its predictions, some of which would otherwise be unexpected. The model therefore explains these predictions’ observed truth. Wikipedia provides a very concise summary of these predictions before going into detail: “The model accounts for the fact that the universe expanded from a very high density and high temperature state, and offers a comprehensive explanation for a broad range of phenomena, including the abundance of light elements, the cosmic microwave background, large scale structure and Hubble’s law.” For more information, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang#Observational_evidence). A refinement, the inflationary Big Bang, explains some other features of the universe; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_(cosmology)#Motivations).

Evidence does need to be “repeatable”, but this doesn’t mean a historical event needs to be made to happen on queue. (How would that even be relevant to whether it happened before?) Reproducibility means that the findings of a piece of research should occur again when others repeat the research. For example, Hubble’s law is observed no matter who looks at the relative velocities of distant galaxies.

Misunderstanding here is not limited to flippiefanus. The Big Bang model is mathematical, but attempts to shoehorn its concepts into English words that weren’t developed for such concepts leads to further misconceptions, viz. user104372. For example:

a) The Big Bang is not an “explosion”; it’s a time-dependent scale factor in an FLRW metric. The scale factor varies over time according to the Friedmann equations, which follow from the general relativity’s equivalent of Newton’s second law, the Einstein field equations. Since the Einstein-Hilbert Lagrangian depends on the scale factor, it is explicitly time-dependent. This is why energy conservation is… a bit of a complicate issue in general relativity.

b) The speed of light is an upper bound on local relative velocities (all velocities are relative to something, e.g. Earth), but not on global relative velocities. Galaxies too far apart have global relative velocities > c, but they cannot observe each other because not enough time has passed, so there is no local relative velocity > c. (The local-global distinction I also important in other contexts, such as Alcubierre metrics.)

c) I have no idea what provable history of ideas is the basis for this nonsense, but as I said the expansion is a time dependence in the FLRW scale factor, which happens because the Friedmann equations does not have stable static solutions.

d) Curvature has two components, extrinsic and intrinsic. The FLRW metric has extrinsic curvature. The open question regards the universe’s intrinsic curvature, i.e. whether the “Friedmann parameter” is positive, zero or negative. Physicists discussing whether the universe is “curved” are referring to that question.

e) The observable universe is finite because the time since the Big Bang is finite, but general relativity and all observations are compatible with both a finite and an infinite universe. The universe could be finite yet unbounded. (To think of an analogy for this geometry, Earth’s surface is “unbounded” because you can travel an arbitrary distance along it, but the surface area is in fact finite; you’re just moving on an oblate spheroid.)

f) “Everywhere” is only vague if you do it in English. In the FLRW metric, the line element’s time dependence due to the scale factor is the same at all choices of spatial coordinates.

Comment: You can't regulate reality with math or a *metric*. You have a very peculiar idea of the scientific method, repeatability, prediction etc.  You interpret the cosmological data according to your model, and that confirms your model. That is the most puerile of logic fallacies.

Comment: @user104372 Your a)-f) were complaints about the theory not making sense, so I corrected your misunderstandings of what the theory says. The scientific case for the theory is that its predictions are correct; see the top of my post. But getting precise predictions in the first place requires a detailed mathematical model. That's how all theories in physics work. (BTW,  in this context "metric" means $ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$.)

Comment: Your correction make sense only in your theory, alas! How do you interpret redshift and expansion? with your theory? where did you prove that space can expand at your specific terms? where you defined space? what is pace made of? Most of all **what** can make space expand, if it can expand, in the first place? **how** does it make expand? WHY at BB and not later or earlier? Give sensible answers, not math

Comment: @user104372 Testing whether predictions are empirically correct requires no "interpretation". The model predicts and thereby explains galaxy redshift and many other observations, but no other model can. If you want to understand this topic well enough to answer your own questions, you should start by learning how the FLRW metric and Friedmann equations are obtained in general relativity (and you may want to look up all the evidence for that theory too).

Comment: Can your theory be falsified? How can the greatest mind ever prove *your* space cannot expand and push massive galaxies  trillions of miles  apart with no energy being created and spent?

Comment: @user104372 Falsification needn't require explaining why expansion is impossible; it need only show some of the predictions are wrong. If the CMB hadn't been a blackbody curve, the theory would be wrong, end of.

Comment: That is false, when some of your 'predictions' fail you simply adjust your model, your metric tailoring the laws of the Universe to your needs.

Comment: @user104372 The metric tensor hasn't been adjusted.

Comment: and who was referring to the metric tensor?

Comment: You said the metric tailors the laws to our needs.

Answer (score 1):

Present day physics is defined as a discipline that studies data, i.e. numbers, whether from experiments or observations, proposes mathematical *models* and considers them valid as long as they are not falsified. A physics mathematical model is falsified if a prediction of the model is false. The historic reaction of physicists to falsification is to expand the mathematical model in a manner that keeps the former fits as successes of the model and corrects the wrong predictions.

The Big Bang model of the universe is a good example of this process.

> [In 1929, Hubble examined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwin_Hubble#Redshift_increases_with_distance) the relation between distance and redshift of galaxies, combining his own measurements of galaxy distances based on Henrietta Swan Leavitt's period-luminosity relationship for Cepheids together with earlier data from fellow astronomer Vesto Slipher plus Milton L. Humason's measurements. He found a rough proportionality of these objects' distances with their redshifts, nowadays termed Hubble's law.

This is the data that needed a theoretical model different that a simple Newtonian model, to be described .

> Yet the reason for the redshift remained unclear. It was *Georges Lemaître, a Belgian Catholic priest and physicist, who found that Hubble's observations supported the Friedmann model of an expanding universe* based on Einstein's equations for General Relativity, which is now known as the Big Bang theory.

So the Big Bang is a mathematical model, within the framework of General Relativity. The words convey the meaning of an initial singularity .  It caught the imagination of physicists and the astronomical and astrophysical observations were fitted with this model at hand.

Until technology brought us the [cosmic microwave background radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background).

The great isotropy in this radiation could not fit with the general General Relativity singularity model , because close to the singularity the various regions could not interact due to the nature of General Relativity, and so no thermodynamic black body isotropy of the early universe could be derived from the BB model as it then stood.

The models expanded and morphed, the present BB model here :

[image]

> [Timeline o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:CMB_Timeline300_no_WMAP.jpg)f the metric expansion of space, where space (including hypothetical non-observable portions of the universe) is represented at each time by the circular sections. On the left the dramatic expansion occurs in the inflationary epoch, and at the center the expansion accelerates (artist's concept; not to scale).

Physicists started working and are still working to bring in Quantum Mechanics to General Relativity. In this plot, an effective quantization is assumed for the very early ages of the universe, which, due to the probabilistic nature of quantum mechanics, can explain the isotropy of the comsic microwave background radiation.

Thus the falsification of the original mathematical  BB model gave rise to the present one, which keeps the successes of the original model and expands it in a manner that removes the falsification of the original model.

This is where we are with the mathematical modeling of the cosmos at present. New observations or new data might change the picture in the future, and more patches may have to be devised.

**Physics is not about truth.** It is about modeling nature successfully within the experimental and observational limits of the times.

In this frame,  the BB model is a successful model.

Comment: "Physics is not about truth. It is about modeling nature..."  A dangerous idea. The model could be empirical and then... theoretical physics simply dies. See this: http://www.network54.com/Forum/304711/thread/1472035791/last-1473187518/Einstein%27s+General+Relativity-+Deductive+Theory+or+Empirical+Concoction "Einstein's General Relativity: Deductive Theory or Empirical Concoction?"

Comment: What does that absurd picture represent? is that supposed to be a plausible, not risible model of Universe (espansion)?

Comment: @user104372  if you know a bit of math , yes. It is an icon of the mathematics

Comment: anna, you are an experimentalist, are you, too reducing physics to math?

Comment: @PentchoValev  the insidious idea is the platonic idea. Theoretical physics is about data, not data about theoretical physics. Without data it is all mathematics.

Comment: @user104372  No, I am using math as a tool, the way I use an accelerator as a tool to create data, to model reality. When it fails, I rethink my tools, take a new tool or modify the existing one

Comment: anna, when you plot a string of data you figure out a formula that represents that curve. if other data fit in , that doesn't mean your formula, because behind a formula there is a vision, is correct. Math is just a tool, *a posteriori*, a tool to organize, classify  and mainly syntethize data. But here you devised a model, a metric and interpret the meagre data you have( redshifs, including CMB ...) that you interpret *through* your model, of cousrse thay mainly fit. That is not scientific.

Comment: "Theoretical physics is about data..."  It is about TRUTH. Einstein's postulate, "the speed of light is independent of the speed of the light source", is either true or false (no third alternative). If it is false, theoretical physics as a whole collapses. (No space here to elaborate).

Comment: @user104372  The data is not meager, and the model works up to now. If it stops working, back to the drawing board, i.e. new models. The history of physics shows that there is no absolute "physics theory" we continually modify the modes.

Comment: @PentchoValev  Only mathematics is about TRUTH, not physics. Theoretical physics is called physics because it models physics data. Otherwise it is mathematics. If General Relativity were not continually validated, with any new measurements and observations, it would have been falsified . If it had not fit astronomical data, it would have remained a curious mathematical theory.

Comment: anna, sure, that is what BB :is a bold project, may be too ambitious, a working hypotesis, full of dark corners and liberties (or rather *poetic licenses*). But answers and comment here, are too arrogant and take for granted it is acceptable. It would be much wiser to say more often: about this we haven't a clue, and forget about the space expanding and blowing up the physical world. I think your answer is the less arrogand and should be accepted

Comment: *the data is not meager* that's apodictical! can you list what concrete data are there outsid redshifts? Isn't the very Hubble law and parameter determined on that *through your own model* ? what are the hard physical facts, evidence that support the huge house of cards? That is what OP was asking.

Comment: @user104372 He/she asks for a course in astronomy and astrophysics. All the data collected up to now, luminocities, lensing, dark matter ... ( I am not an astrophysicist) are consistent with the model, i.e. do not falsify it, and there does not exist another model that is not falsified.

Comment: anna, bringing in dark matter as "evidence" really takes the cake! You have lost touch with reality.

Comment: @user104372  "dark matter" is shorthand for newtonian missing mass. IT IS A MEASURED PHENOMENON

Answer (score -1):

From a purely scientific point of view, one can never say whether it really happened this way or whether there could not be other explanations. The reason is the big bang is a historic event that happened only once, while science requires repeatability.

*Addition*:

Perhaps it is worth pointing out some misunderstanding. There is a difference between a scientific theory that directly describes a physical phenomenon (or set of phenomena) such as electromagnetism and scientifically *feasible* theory that describes the historical events, such as the big bang theory. In the former case one can directly test the theory based on experiments that accesses nature behaviour. In the latter can one need to distinguish between the feasibile theory and the historic event. What the feasible theory can be tested in a scientific manner one cannot make the connection between between the feasibile theory and the historic event, unless one has direct evidence (i.e. direct observation of the event) or one can rule out all possible alternatives. In the case of the big bang theory neither is possible, because no one was present to record the event, nor can we know that there would not in the future be some other theory that can also explain the observations that are currently being made.

Now, I know people are very passionate about their favorite theories, especially if it is the theory that one spends one's career on, but there is something to be said for scientific honesty. Without scientific honesty, one can get into the situation where people are easily mislead. The big bang theory is a beautiful feasible theory and I'd be happy to say that it could well be the actual way that it happened, but such a conviction would not be based on science.

Comment: Why the downvote? *flippiefanus* has just reported one of the basic principles of physics and epistemology. What cannot be repeated is outside the scope od *any* science, can't be the object of scientific, credible investigation

Comment: @ See my own explanation of what repeatability is.

Comment: @user104372, downvotes are just people's personal subjective ideas. It is not based on scientific rigor.

Comment: Perhaps that is why the *big bang model* is a model, not a theory.

Answer (score -2):

*"The big bang model is first discussed when the people witnesses that almost every galaxies are speeding away from each other"*

People didn't witness that. Rather, they (Hubble) observed that the redshift increases with distance, which can have a different explanation. For instance, as the photon travels through space (in a STATIC universe), it may bump into vacuum particles and as a result lose speed (energy), similarly to a golf ball losing speed due to the resistance of the air:

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0262407911603059 
 New Scientist: "Vacuum has friction after all. A ball spinning in a vacuum should never slow down, right? Wrong. It turns out quantum effects can create a type of friction in the void."

http://www.nature.com/news/superfluid-spacetime-points-to-unification-of-physics-1.15437 
 Nature: "As waves travel through a medium, they lose energy over time. This dampening effect would also happen to photons traveling through spacetime, the researchers found."

Comment: Vacuum friction can't explain the specific pattern of Hubble's law. If you write per-photon energy of light from a galaxy as a function of distance using Hubble's law, you get a formula that vacuum friction would not obtain. In particular, the dependence on the angle between the directions of emission and relative motion is explained by the Doppler effect and only the Doppler effect.

Comment: "Vacuum friction can't explain the specific pattern of Hubble's law."  On the contrary, it can even provide an alternative to the "accelerated expansion" interpretation. See this: http://www.network54.com/Forum/304711/thread/1461086777/last-1461086777/Vacuum+Friction+and+Hubble+Redshift "Vacuum Friction and Hubble Redshift"

Comment: I found no discussion of acceleration. Please link to the theorists' maths: yours needs work. It is a photon's four-momentum that should appear in the differential equation, not its speed (which is $c$). Any time-dependent frequency has first-order corrections $\propto t$, but your model doesn't explain the $\theta$ dependence due to the Doppler effect. Nor does it explain any other evidence for the Big Bang, or why general relativity would be wrong to predict the Friedman equations that describe it, or the evidence for general relativity.

Comment: J.G. : "It is a photon's four-momentum that should appear in the differential equation, not its speed (which is c)."  This is funny but you don't seem to be joking.