# What are the evidences of the big bang theory?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, big-bang

We can say about a mention is scientific if we can analyze and repeat that mentioned process.

Our theory of the origin of the world is the big bang theory, which say that there was the absolutely nothing, and sometime occured something which explode this nothing (simplify summery). We are not able to analyze this process, and we have never can explode the absolutely nothing.

I see that we are living in an expanding universe and the opposite of this expansion means that one starting point is needed. But it is just a theory not an scientific mention (even so every scientist talk about this theory like a fact).

So simplify I would you like to ask that what evidences attest to the big bang theory is more than a simply theory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11136/ and links therein.

Comment: Its called Cosmic Microwave Background radiation. Which is nothing but the relic of Big Bang.

Comment: Yours is a frequent mistake. Theory and hypothesis may be synonyms in everyday language, but in scientific language they are not. The big bang theory is not an hypothesis, as you are suggesting. In general a theory is a set of laws verified through experiment and observations, far from a simple guess. In astrophysics and cosmology we lack the experimentation part, but fortunately we have plenty of observation.

Comment: Also, the usage of the term explosion is counter-productive in this sense, and is used mostly to ridicule the theory. Please refrain from such usage, as that is NOT what the Big Bang is. It's an expansion, not an explosion.

Comment: Current theory does not say that "there was absolutely nothing".

Answer (score 2):

There are four main pieces of evidence that support the Big Bang theory:

1. The expansion of the universe according to Hubble's law (as indicated by the redshifts of galaxies)
2. The discovery and measurement of the cosmic microwave background and the relative abundances of light elements produced by Big Bang nucleosynthesis
3. Observations of galaxy formation and evolution
4. The distribution of large-scale cosmic structures

For more information, see [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang#Observational_evidence). I'll be adding more information as I have time.