# What are the problems or shortcomings of the Big bang theory?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, big-bang

I know Big Bang is the most accepted model among scientists today and has been for several decades but I am just curious to see if it has any flaws as well.

1. So what are its flaws?
2. And what are the reason behind big bang theory being unable to explain those flaws?
3. And what will it need to explain or fix those flaws?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11136/2451 and links therein.

Comment: the big bang model has a short list of known flaws (that is, things which are observed in the universe but not explained by it). a careful analysis of the big bang model in light of those flaws reveals the cause(s) of those shortcomings, which are well-documented. a short list of modifications to that model have been proposed to fix the flaws, chief among those mods is the so-called inflation model (and its variants). Have a look at "inflation" on wikipedia (under cosmology, not economics) and come back here if there's anything you need explained in more detail and we can take a whack at it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What has been proved about the big bang, and what has not?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11136/what-has-been-proved-about-the-big-bang-and-what-has-not)

Comment: An issue that people don't talk about much, probably because nobody has a clue how to deal with it, is why the big bang had low entropy. If the initial conditions of the universe had been chosen at random, then we would expect with 100% probability to get a maximum-entropy universe, i.e., one in which everything was already in thermal equilibrium. Penrose's CCC was a failed attempt to get at this.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a bad question, but there's a subtle problem with it I'll have to address to give an answer, which is that there's no such thing as "the" BBT. The BB as a historical event doesn't have (as much) predictive power before we add theoretical details that have varied over time. So even if we answer your three part-questions, what comes next will likely be thought of as "a" BBT once its details are known.

Since "the BB happened" was first proposed, we've added a positive cosmological constant, cold dark matter and, depending on how you define "the consensus model", early-universe inflation. These each had empirical motivations, and if you'd asked your question a few decades ago the answers to its parts would have been something like:

1. It can't explain flatness, homogeneity, and the very low magnetic monopole density required given that they're unobserved. (The $\Lambda > 0$ and CDM details are empirically recent.)
2. The maths says something else if you assume the time-dependence of the scale factor that follows from the then-expected historical profile of what kind of matter dominates.
3. That question was probably hard to answer at the time, but in hindsight we needed the effective early value of $w$ to be negative enough, certainly $w<-\frac{1}{3}$ and ideally $0\le w+1\ll 1$.

Today, most physicists consider inflationary cosmology the most promising approach to these. Assuming they're right, today we have very some different problems to worry about, and our desire to do something new has *theoretical* motivations. These are problems of quantum gravity, which unfortunately also have a bearing on how we should model inflation.

Traditionally Big Bang cosmology has been an exercise in general relativity, but we know gravity's behaviour on small length sales will require something new, and the way the Big Bang worked very early on will depend on how quantum gravity works. So:

1. We don't know what happened in the "first" Planck time or so; it's not even known whether anything existed "before" the Big Bang. Although Stephen Hawking has popularised the analogy that this question might be as wrong-headed as asking what's North of the North Pole, he's also contributed to [a model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartle%E2%80%93Hawking_state) in which a pre-BB era occurs.
2. We don't know nearly enough about quantum gravity to settle the details of the Planck epoch. (In fact, this might remain a purely theoretical, not empirical, question indefinitely.) For example, string theory's predictions differ from those of loop quantum gravity, or (insert your favourite even less popular alternative here; see [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gravity#Other_approaches)). There are reasons to favour string theory, to be sure; but they are theoretical reasons that attract a lot of controversy, not empirical reasons that attract a lot of consensus.
3. Explaining the needs of quantum gravity would probably take far too long for an adequate answer here, so I suggest you begin learning about this topic [here](https://philo-phys-qg.sciencesconf.org/data/pages/Carlip_Quantum_Gravity.pdf), then choose what to read next based on which sub-topics take your initial interest, your mathematical expertise etc.

Comment: The way you describe things like the flatness and monopole problems, you make it sound as if they had all been solved. Presumably you feel that the solution is or will be inflation, but I think that's premature. There is not yet any strong observational confirmation of inflation, and the theoretical framework is very shaky. You then pass to quantum gravity (QG) issues. IMO these are not scientific issues because we do not have any access to empirical data that would probe QG. So saying that these are now issues to be solved is IMO far too optimistic.

Comment: @BenCrowell Thanks for those concerns; I've updated the answer to address them. We can only hope the issues you consider unscientific due to being beyond the scope of empirical data will eventually be addressable that way. There's no guarantee of this, but considering how once "philosophical" atomic theory became scientific I'm hopeful.

Comment: *Today, however, inflationary cosmology is considered by many if not all physicists to explain this.* I don't think this is accurate. It might be more accurate to say that most physicists consider it the most promising avenue for future work on these issues.

Comment: @BenCrowell Added.